Systemd timer with OnStartupSec and OnUnitActiveSec runs immediately at boot
I have this timer:
$ systemctl cat ansible-pull.timer
# /etc/systemd/system/ansible-pull.timer
[Unit]
Description=Starts ansible-pull
Requires=ansible-pull.service

[Timer]
OnStartupSec=10min
OnUnitActiveSec=6h

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target

Calling this service:
$ systemctl cat ansible-pull.service
# /etc/systemd/system/ansible-pull.service
[Unit]
Description=Runs ansible-pull

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=ansible
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ansible-pull

And it generally works as expected (runs 10 mins after boot and then every 6h), except that it also runs once immediately during boot, which I'd like to avoid.
I would have expected this for a timer with Persistent=true, but it's not set here and defaults to false.
Some more debugging data:
$ systemctl list-dependencies --reverse ansible-pull.timer
ansible-pull.timer
● └─timers.target
●   └─basic.target
○     ├─initrd.target
●     └─multi-user.target
●       └─graphical.target

$ systemctl list-dependencies --reverse ansible-pull.service
ansible-pull.service
● └─ansible-pull.timer

$ find /{etc,usr/lib}/systemd/ -name ansible-pull.\*
/etc/systemd/system/ansible-pull.service
/etc/systemd/system/ansible-pull.timer
/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/ansible-pull.timer


Did you enable the service (systemctl enable ansible-pull.service)? What is the output of systemctl is-enabled ansible-pull.service?

You should remove the line
Requires=ansible-pull.service

in the timer. When the timer was started by timers.target, this line says you must first start ansible-pull.service.

D'oh … thank you!
